# Excel Date calculation using todays date negative values

Tags: excel, date, negative-number

When using a simple sum to calculate a % how can i make the % return the value of Zero when the value is negative.

=SUM(P17/N17)

Comment: Dates? Or percentages?

Comment: What values are in P17 and N17? Taking the MAX of zero and that quotient should not result in True. But I'll fix it if you can let me know what P17 and N17 are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=MAX(0,SUM(P17/N17))
```